# How to add elements to the current open activity Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, mobile

I am new with android and i am trying to understand how to add element to open activity layout and to display the changes immediately.
is it possible by adding with `addView`? i tried with no succeed.

```
    TextView sv = new TextView(this);
    TextView b = new TextView(this);
    sv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    b.setText("ggg");
    sv.setText("asdsadasdasdasdasdas");

    RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
    ll.addView(sv);
    ll.addView(b);
    this.setContentView(ll);
```

in this way its delete everything was before

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: TextView sv = new TextView(this);
        TextView b = new TextView(this);
        sv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        b.setText("ggg");
        sv.setText("asdsadasdasdasdasdas");

        RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ll.addView(sv);
        ll.addView(b);
        this.setContentView(ll);

Comment: @TzurielYamin first thing don't post code in comment please edit it in question and your code seems wrong because first thing you have to get that relative layout reference from layout or set relativelayout as your setcontentview() instead of layout

Comment: for proper help upload your layout file also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a new RelativeLayout if you want to add elements to a pre-existing layout. You should instead create a reference to the existing RelativeLayout like this.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
textView.setText("New TextView");

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewByID(R.id.layout_id);
layout.addView(textView);
```

Replace layout_id with the id of your XML layout.

Comment: TNX man. i have another Q, can i give to the new textview ID?
and how can i set it relative to other elements?
TNX

Comment: Use `textView.setId(int ID)` to set an ID. Refer to [The android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) for a table containing the java ways of adjusting XML atributes (ctrl+f XML Attributes).

Comment: TNX. from some reason i get error when i am trying to insert number

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add at runtime. Get View instance from inflate function and add into layout which you have in your activity. Show me your code if where you are facing issue.

Comment: TextView sv = new TextView(this);
        TextView b = new TextView(this);
        sv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        b.setText("ggg");
        sv.setText("asdsadasdasdasdasdas");

        RelativeLayout ll = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ll.addView(sv);
        ll.addView(b);
        this.setContentView(ll);

Comment: setLayoutParam to fill parent in relative layout and setbackground color. Because i think it is added but you are not able to see that.

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView` replaces your layout, there's `addContentView` which adds to the current layout instead.
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView(android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

**But this is not the way to do it.**

Define your basic layout with some root Layout (e.g. LinearLayout), after initial setContentView, do a findViewById to get a reference to that layout and then you can add views to it in real-time

Code:

```
onCreate(...) {
   setContentView(R.layout.my_initial_layout);
   root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_root_view);
}

whenSomethingHappens() {
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
   tv.setText("Hello!");
   root.addView(tv);
}
```